# PHP procedure for returning a random number in the range 65, 66, ..., 90, 97, 98, ..., 122

Tags: php

My web hosting service doesn't have a debugger, so I don't have any insight into why my procedure is failing. I made the following function to generate a random string of length `n`, and tried to optimize it as much as possible. Any idea what's wrong and how I could possibly make it more elegant? I just started learning PHP, so it's possible I've expected some syntax from other languages to transfer to PHP when in fact they don't.

```
function rand_str(int $n)
{
    $str = "";
    for (;$n > 0; --$n)
    {
        /* ASCII vals are 'A'=65, 'B'=66, ..., 'Z'=90, 'a'=97, 'b'=98, ..., 'c'=122 */
        int $val = rand(0,51);
        $str += (char)($val < 26 ? $val + 65 : $val % 26 + 97); 
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: And on your local machine,  where you have a debugger, it works? Somehow I'm suspect of your excuse why you can't debug this yourself

Comment: `$val` not `int $val`. You don't declare types like that.

Comment: Also `rand_str($n)` not `rand_str(int $n)`. You can't typehint basic types, only objects and arrays. (And callables in the latest version, IIRC.)

Comment: `(char)` is also not a valid way to cast, instead use `(string)` if you need to do that (which you don't in this case, weak typing and all...). Or did you mean `chr()`? Then it's a typo, you aren't passing a value to it.  Also you can't type hint with `int` and if you could the proper syntax would be `(int)`.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. In case you didn't see my edit, I also added some information on enabling warnings and error reporting on your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working version of your code:

```
function rand_str($n)
{
    $str = "";
    while($n-- > 0)
    {
        /* ASCII vals are 'A'=65, 'B'=66, ..., 'Z'=90, 'a'=97, 'b'=98, ..., 'c'=122 */
        $val = rand(0,51);
        $str .= chr($val < 26 ? $val + 65 : $val % 26 + 97); 
    }
    return $str;
}
```

If you're only going to use two parts of the `for` loop, you may as well use a `while`. Strings are concatenated using `.=`, not `+=`. You don't specify types in PHP. The function `chr` returns a character from an ascii code.

This seems like quite a brute-force way of learning a new language. It's not a very good idea to just assume how things are going to work!

As an aside, even if you don't have access to your server configuration, you can enable warnings by adding these lines to the top of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

This should help you with debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```
function rand_str($n)
{
    $str = "";
    for (;$n > 0; --$n)
    {
        $val = rand(0,51);
        $str .= ($val < 26) ? $val + 65 : $val % 26 + 97; //Here you have to concatenate with a '.'
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works and it's more flexible I think.

```
function rand_str(int $n)
{
    for ($str = "", $n>0; --$n)
    {
        $val = rand(0,1) ? rand(ord("A"),ord("Z")) : rand(ord("a"),ord("z"));
        $str .= chr ($val); 
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the $str be local to the for loop?

Comment: No it won't.. I've tested the code, it works perfectly and you don't have to know the ASCII values